# Сортировка колонок в Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм вот с такими именами колонок:

```
columns = [
  '10', '10!', '10*', '10**',
  '2', '2!', '2*',
  '3', '3!', '3*', '3**',
  '4', '4!', '4*', '4**',
  '5', '5!', '5*', '5**',
  '6', '6!', '6*', '6**',
  '7', '7!', '7*', '7**',
  '8', '8!', '8*', '8**',
  '9', '9!', '9*', '9**'
]
```

Имена колонок - строки. Отсортированы по алфавиту, как строки.

Есть ли способ отсортировать колонки датафрейма по порядку цифр в начале строк?

Вот так:

```
columns = [
  '2', '2!', '2*',
  '3', '3!', '3*', '3**',
  '4', '4!', '4*', '4**',
  '5', '5!', '5*', '5**',
  '6', '6!', '6*', '6**',
  '7', '7!', '7*', '7**',
  '8', '8!', '8*', '8**',
  '9', '9!', '9*', '9**',
  '10', '10!', '10*', '10**'
]
```

Comment: использовать для сортировки ключ:  `sorted(columns,key=lambda x: int(x.strip('!*')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог первый комментарий к вопросу.

Полное решение:

```
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: int(x.strip('!*')))]
```